# Finding Jordanizing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}4&-5&2 \\ 5&-7&3\\ 6&-9&4 \end{matrix}\right)$$ And I found B, A's Jordan form to be: $$B=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)$$, so that there is invertible matrix S, so that $S^{-1}AS=B$.

How do I find S?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How did you find B ??

Comment: $S$ is the matrix having a Jordan basis as its columns.

Comment: $S$ is made up of the colums from the eigenvectors you found to come up with $B$.

Comment: That's what I wanted the OP to reply, @Amzoti...he *already* must have, almost-almost, $\;S\;$ ...

Comment: There is an algorithm to determine $B$ without knowing anything about $S$. I'm guessing this is what the OP did.

Comment: Of, we (or I, at least) know that, @GitGud...yet the eigenvalues , eigenvectors and generalized eig. are to be calculated, and from here to form S seems a rather short step.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It is basically a dup of my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599977/finding-jordan-form/600029?noredirect=1#comment1264879_600029

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods...perhaps the simplest is to take the generalized eigenspace $\text{Null}((A-\lambda I)^d)$ and pick a random vector $v$ in the space. It will almost certainly be in $\text{Null}((A-\lambda I)^d) \setminus \text{Null}((A-\lambda I)^{d-1})$. Then $\{v, (A-\lambda I)v, \dotsc, (A-\lambda I)^{d-1}v\}$ are linearly independent (this requires a short proof). There's your basis for that particular Jordan block. Repeat for each block.