# Find the Jordan normal form J for A and a Jordan basis for A.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-3&-1&1\\
-1&-3&1\\
-2&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}.$

Question:

$(i)$ Determine the characteristic equation of A, hence find the eigenvalues of A.

$(ii)$ Determine the minimal polynomial of A.

$(iii)$ Write down the Jordan normal form J for A.

$(iv)$ Find a Jordan basis for A.

My attempt for $(i)$ is to find $ \text{det}(A−\lambda I)=0$. I ended up with $(\lambda + 2)^3$ so the eigenvalues are all equal $-2$.

Comment: Do you know how to find the determinant of a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: @Petaro I always mess up with the calculation and get something really weird, I just did another calculation, Do i get correct answer this time?

Comment: Yep, there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is 
$$\chi_A(t) = \text{det}(A-t\Bbb{1})$$

where $\Bbb{1} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

After a few calculation you should get $\chi_A(t)=(t+2)^3$. So you have one eigenvalue with multiplicity $3$.

Note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(t)=(t+2)^2$ since 
$$(A+2\Bbb{1})^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 &1\\-1&-1&1\\-2&-2&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 &1\\-1&-1&1\\-2&-2&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This tells you that the Jordan Normal form of $A$ will be like this

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
Since the number $2$ on the minimal polynomial gives you the length of the Jordan Blocks.

Now comes the difficult part. That is the part where you need to evaluate the Jordan basis, that is a basis that express your function in the form of $J$. Normally you need to distinguish between a [Nillpotent endomorphismus](http://planetmath.org/nilpotenttransformation) and a [not nillpotent endomorphismus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599977/finding-jordan-form?rq=1) 
In your case if you define 
$$\Phi:= A + 2\Bbb{1}$$

You have a nillpotent endomorphism, since you know that $\Phi^2 =0$ by the minimal polynomial. Wi will find a Basis $T$ with respect to which 
$$T\Phi T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

And this basis will also be the same basis that will make your $A$ look like $J$, indeed
\begin{align*} T\Phi T^{-1} &= \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \\
TAT^{-1}&= \begin{pmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

I'll write you a summary of the theory that explain how to evaluate the Jordan Normal Form of a nillpotent endomorphism. You can find more detail in [this](http://www.exlibris.ch/de/buecher-buch/deutschsprachige-buecher/gerd-fischer/lineare-algebra/id/9783834809964?gclid=Cj0KEQjwvLGfBRDfkrr19KDS-7YBEiQA8CoFJ85anN7gIRm27eP5DXzhXS_Pu9oLavWXp7Jf4wWi7ZwaAtJh8P8HAQ) book.

Let $U_l:= \text{Ker} (\Phi^l)$ Then we have

\begin{align*}
U_2 &= \text{Ker}(\Phi^2) = \text{Ker}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} = \Bbb{R}^3 \\
U_1 &= \text{Ker}(\Phi) =\text{Ker}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 &1\\-1&-1&1\\-2&-2&2\end{pmatrix} = \text{span} ( \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix})\\
U_0 &= \text{Ker}(\Phi^0)= \{0\}
\end{align*}

Note that we can complete each time $\Bbb{R}^3$ by completing the base. For instance

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{R}^3 = U_2 &= U_1 \oplus W_2\\
\Bbb{R}^3 = U_2 &= U_0 \oplus W_1 \oplus W_2 = W_1 \oplus W_2
\end{align*}
Where the subspaces $W_i$ are spanned by those vectors who complete the basis **and** such that $U_i \supset W_i$ for all $i$. The only thing that remains to do is to find the basis  of the subspaces $W_i$ we begin with $W_2$.

You know that $\text{dim}(\Bbb{R}^3)=3$ and that $\text{dim}(U_1)=2$ since $U_1$ is spanned by two linear independent vector that we already evaluated above. This implies that $\text{dim}(W_2) = 1$ and hence that there is a vector in $W_2$ that completes the basis and that spans $\Bbb{R}^3$. Note that this vector must **satisfy** the property $U_2 \supset W_2$, but since $U_2 = \Bbb{R}^3$ all we need to do is find a vector $w_1^{(2)}$ that is linear independent from $( \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix})$.

I've chosen the vector $w_1^{(2)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ since this is linear independent from the other two. You can check this for instance by evaluating the determinant of this matrix

$$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \neq 0$$

That is the matrix that contains the vectors that must be linear independent. Now you need to find a basis of $W_1$. Considering the fact that $W_2$ has dimension $1$ you know that $W_1$ must have dimension $2$ and hence that it must be spanned by *two* linear independent vectors. You can find one vector by evaluating $\Phi w_1^{(2)}$ and the other must be found in order to satisfy the property $U_1 \supset W_1$. Summarizing we have

Basis of $W_1 = (\Phi w_1^{(2)}, w_1^{(1)})$ where $w_1^{(1)}$ is the vector that mus satisfy the property given above. I've chosen $w_1^{(1)}= \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}^T$ since this vector is linear independent from $\Phi w_1^{(2)}$ and $w_1{(2)}$, indeed we have

$$\text{det}(\Phi w_1^{(2)}, w_1^{(2)}, w_1^{(1)}) = \text{det}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & -1 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{:=T^{-1}}\neq 0$$

Finally we have found our basis of $W_1$ and $W_2$ and our basis $T^{-1}$ is exactly $(\Phi w_1^{(2)}, w_1^{(2)}, w_1^{(1)})$ Indeed you can check that

$$TAT^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-2&1&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}=J$$

I know it may sound a little confusing, but i always used this method and it has always worked. If you want to practice more solve the first exercises of [this](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/linalg2/serie10.pdf) exercises sheet. You can find the solution [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/linalg2/loesung10.pdf)

Comment: Thank you :)  To be honest, What really confused me is that you were using det(A−t1) instead of det(A−λI) and It took me some time to see how you did there in the beginning :P The rest are fine. Thank you again.

Comment: @user164945 You are welcome, sorry about that, i really didn't thought about it :D