# Is this the right way of determining the Jordan normal form and Jordan basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

For the linear map $Tv = Av$, T : $\mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{3}$, where

$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & -2 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 2 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$

We are given the characteristic polynomial of T, $ch(x) = (x-2)(x-1)^2$

So far I have found that by solving:

$(I_3 - A)v = 0$

$V_1(1) = span(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}
)$

$(I_3 - A)^2v = 0$

$V_2(1) = span(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 1 \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}
)$

and

$(2I_3 - A)v = 0$

$V_1(2) = span(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}
)$

for each eigenspace,

Does this mean that the Jordan basis is:

$B = ({  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 1 \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}})$

and the JNF is

$J=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
$

due to the multiplicities of the eigenvalues.

Would this be correct?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: "Have I correctly determined the JNF" - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897943/find-the-jordan-normal-form-j-for-a-and-a-jordan-basis-for-a?rq=1), how to do it.

Comment: Your $B$ is not a Jordan basis (nor a *basis* at all, since it's made of three identical vectors).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli sorry about that I have now edited it to be the vectors I wanted to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Learn how to verify your work**. Let (by abuse of notation) $B$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectors of the basis $B$. Is it true that $BJB^{-1}=A$? If it is so (and if $J$ is in Jordan form, which is obvious to check), then your Jordan basis is correct.

Equivalently, you may check that $BJ=AB$ and that $B$ is invertible, which is easier.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to find a *Jordan basis* is *not* to begin by finding the eigenvectors  for the eigenvalues with multiplicity $>1$, but finding first the generalised eigenvectors with highest level, then cascading until obtaining the eigenvectors as images of generalised eigenvectors.

Let's see in more detail what this procedure becomes in the present situation.

You have two eigenvalues: $1$ (multiplicity $2$) and $2$ (multiplicity $1$). Further more you can check the eigenspace $E_1$ has dimension $1$, so we have to consider the subspace $\ker (A-I)^2$ (generalised eigenspace), choose a vector $v_2\in \ker (A-I)^2\setminus\ker(A-I)$, and set $v_1=(A-I)v_2$. $v_1\in E_1$.

Add a vector $v_3\in E_2$. By construction, the basis $(v_1, v_2,v_3)$  is a Jordan basis.