# Jordan decomposition algorithm

Tags: vector-spaces, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form

I'm trying to calculate the value of a matrix function. As far as I understood, this is done by first decomposing my matrix $A$ into $PJP^{-1}$. Where $J$ is in Jordan normal form.

However, this appears to be a ton of work for $3\times3$ matrices so I'm thinking I might be using the wrong algorithm.

The way I do it is first calculating the characteristic polynomial. This is already one computation of a $3\times3$ determinant and then simplification. After than, I solve the $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for each eigenvalue to get the geometric multiplicities. Then, as it usually is the case, I end up missing 2 of 3 eigenvectors so I don't have a Jordan basis. This means that I need to solve the $AP=PJ$ system where I usually only know the first column of $P$. After all this is done, I have to find the inverse of $P$.

Then, solving the task at hand is relatively simple and requires computing a couple of derivatives and a few matrix multiplications.

How can this process be simplified and sped up? What are the techniques I can apply here in general? Are there any that can be applied for some specific cases of $A$?

Comment: Are you interested in finding *only* the matrix $J$ or also the matrix $P$? In the first case a faster way is to look at the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$, but in the second case you need to do your calculations. (There are actually more ways to find $P$ but every method involves many calculations).

Comment: Is $J$ enough for calculating the value of a matrix function? My textbook says no.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but could you explain what do you mean with *value of a matrix function*?

Comment: Something like $A-e^A$

Comment: Ok. There you also will need to evaluate $P$. Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599977/finding-jordan-form?rq=1) example is helpful. (I think it requires less calculations than yours, in particular it avoids you the step where you need to solve $AP=PJ$)

Comment: Use matlab, wolframalpha or any other program that is made for calculations like that. E.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2C2%2C3%29%2C%282%2C3%2C4%29%2C%283%2C4%2C5%29%29

Comment: Well, I can't use matlab on my exams. Other than that, I have not found a way to make wolfram calculate matrix functions. It just applies the function to each element.

Comment: Luka why don't you give us your example so that we can work it out together?